# Maven 3 warnings: Failure to transfer asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

while building giraph jar with dependencies we are getting following warnings.. really not sure how to resolve these.. we already tried

useProjectArtifact as false

and

unpack as true

both dosent seem to work

any suggestion how to resolve these...??

```
[WARNING] Failure to transfer asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from file:../../local.repository/trunk was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local.repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory

[WARNING] Failure to transfer asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from file:../../local.repository/trunk was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local.repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

Comment: Behind a proxy ? Firewall ?

Comment: Have you changed settings.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a connection problem, proxy or firewall, so you can contour this solutions:

- Explicit refer the ASM dependency. Take a look at the correct version and try to add it into your pom (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm). After that, execute `mvn install` to ensure that's everything ok.
- If it doesn't work, you can try to manually download the dependency and copy it inside your local repository (local folder ".m2"), probably at "/.m2/asm/asm/". Isn't the best solution, but perhaps this can solve your problem.

Hope it helps!